# Remove class on all other instances of Polymer object in Dart?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to build a simple accordion Polymer component. I have it working so when I click on an item in the list, an `open` class is added to the item which shows its contents.

I don't want to be able to have multiple items open at a time, so in my click function, I essentially want to say:

```
$(".list-item").on("click", function() {
    $("list-item").removeClass("open");
    $(this).addClass("open");
}
```

Of course this is in jQuery and not Dart...so that doesn't help me much.

What's the above equivalent in Dart?

Here's what I have working right now (just opens each clicked item, but doesn't close others in the process).

```
     _openedChanged: function() {
      if (this.opened) {
        this.toggleClass('open', true);
      }
      else {
        this.toggleClass('open', false);
      }
      this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', this.opened ? 'true' : 'false');
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove a class from all `list-item` elements in Dart, you could do:

```
querySelectorAll('list-item').forEach((item) => item.classes.remove('open'));
```